# Browser support for SVG <use>?

Tags: svg

I'm having a hard time finding some *precise* information on the browser support for the [`<use>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) to include inline SVGs. There is a Can I Use page on [SVG fragment identifiers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fragment), but as I understand this is only for the `<view>` element. Any idea?

Comment: They all support `<use>`. Bugs in implementations vary though.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Sphinxxx yes I also link to this page in my post but it only mentions the latest versions of the most popular browsers, I'm looking for something more precise / comprehensive.

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for. What information is missing? What does **precise** mean?

Comment: @RobertLongson older browser versions

Comment: who cares about that. older browser's market share is negligable.

Comment: That's quite a bold statement. The share is far from negligible if you want to offer a good browsing experience for all users.